# Batch renaming files as if editing a file of filenames

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, rename, filenames

I am looking for a command / package for Ubuntu that would generate a file containing all the filenames under the current directory and allow me to edit the file. I could then rename the files in bulk as I like. Once I saved the edit, it would automatically apply the renaming.

I have used this command/package in the past but could not find it. I am not looking for rename or sed, etc. The advantage of this approach is to allow me edit the filenames using Vim that I am more familiar with, than remembering how to use sed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around the Internet I finally found the tool:

Simply install `renameutils` and use `qmv`.

For example, `$ qmv -f do`.
The command generates a file containing the filenames under the current dir, editing and saving this file to apply bulk renaming.

I posted it here because I like it way more than using `rename`. All thanks go to the original answer, [this great answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/840190).!